# Cannot invoke "City.getX()" because "city[i]" is null

Tags: java

Hey Im working on a homework and i got stuck, i need to return the name of the two citys with the least amount of distance between them, the citys must be in order that the second one is after the first one (first i, second i+1);
Thanks.

```java
public class Maincity {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        City [] cityArr = new City[10];
        String[] nameArr = new String[] {"Hadera","Beer Sheva","Haifa", "Ashdod", "Eilat", "Jerusalem", "Ashkelon", "Tel Aviv", "Hertzila", "Netanya"};

        for (int i=0;i<cityArr.length;i++) {
            int rRandom = (int)(Math.random() * 100000) + 10000;
            int xRandom = (int)(Math.random() * 10000) + 1000;
            int yRandom = (int)(Math.random() * 10000) + 1000;
            City ir = new City(nameArr[i], rRandom, xRandom, yRandom);
            System.out.println(ir);
        }

        System.out.println(Distance(cityArr));
    }

    public static int Distance(City[] city) {
        int min = 100000000;

        for (int i = 0; i < city.length; i++) {
            int newX = city[i].getX() - city[i + 1].getX();
            int newY = city[i].getY() - city[i + 1].getY();
            newX = (int) Math.pow(newX, 2);
            newY = (int) Math.pow(newY, 2);
            int nDistance = (int) (Math.sqrt(newX) + Math.sqrt(newY));

            if (nDistance < min) {
                min = nDistance;
            }
        }

        return min;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should fill your `cityArr` with the `City` objects you created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: After doing `City ir = new City(nameArr[i],rRandom, xRandom,  yRandom);` put this Object into the array `cityArr[i] = ir;`

Comment: also make for loop `int i=0;i<city.length-1;i++`

Comment: @Himeshgoswami No, the `-1` there is incorrect -- the OP has it right. For example, if the array had length 3, you would want `i` to take on 3 values: 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: Thanks to oracle for improving the error message!

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 problems:

1. You didn't put the city into array.
2. The index calculation (i+1) throwed ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] nameArr=new String[] {"Hadera","Beer Sheva","Haifa", "Ashdod", "Eilat", "Jerusalem", "Ashkelon", "Tel Aviv", "Hertzila", "Netanya"};
        City [] cityArr= new City[nameArr.length];
        for(int i=0;i<cityArr.length;i++) {
            int rRandom = (int)(Math.random()*100000)+10000;
            int xRandom = (int)(Math.random()*10000)+1000;
            int yRandom = (int)(Math.random()*10000)+1000;
            City ir = new City(nameArr[i],rRandom, xRandom,  yRandom);
            cityArr[i] = ir;
            System.out.println(ir);
        }
        System.out.println(Distance(cityArr));
    }
    public static int Distance(City[] city) {
        int min =100000000;
        for(int i=0;i<city.length;i++) {
            int nextCityIndex = (i+1) % city.length;
            int newX =city[i].getX() - city[nextCityIndex].getX();
            int newY =city[i].getY() - city[nextCityIndex].getY();
            newX = (int) Math.pow(newX, 2);
            newY = (int) Math.pow(newY, 2);
            int nDistance = (int) (Math.sqrt(newX)+Math.sqrt(newY));
            if(nDistance<min) {
                min=nDistance;
            }

        }
        return min;
    }
```